# Connect socket.io to different address

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a django system that has a build in chat that's been build with socket.io.

Today I was trying to get everything on webfaction so I registered the django part to http://example.com and the node/socket part to http://example.com/chat.

I have already managed to serve `socket.io.js` to the browser, but the connections are not working. The client is trying to connect to http://example.com instead of http://example.com/chat so I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421523295233-0
```

On the client side I wrote this `var socket = io.connect('http://example.com/chat/')` to establish the connection

And on the server I wrote this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()

var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(20964, "127.0.0.1");

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Using the server IP Address is no possible as it might change in the future.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your server is listening on port 20964 and you're requesting without any (i.e. port 80)

Comment: On client write this: `var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:20964/chat/')`

Comment: @laggingreflex I tried it too but it didn't work

Comment: Your server seems to be set up wrong. Try `var server = http.createServer(app); var io = require('socket.io')(server); server.listen(20964, "127.0.0.1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `path` option on client:

```
io('http://example.com', {path: '/chat/socket.io'});
```

This is because socket.io client tries to connect to `/socket.io` by default, but in your case, it's hosted under `/chat`, thus you have to change the setting of where socket.io connects with the option.

Comment: Or stop trying to use the `/chat` path at all and just let socket.io use its default of `http://example.com/socket.io` which just works automatically.  This path is not visible to the end user so it's kind of pointless to change it.

Comment: @jrfriend00 I can immediately think of a use case that one would want to change the `path`. Suppose you are proxying with nginx your nodejs server; and you are serving static files through nginx on `/`. And the proxying happens on `/api/`. You you try to connect through `/socket.io`, it won't work, unless you do the `path` setting as above. Nice answer!